# SQL Server - EXECUTE permission

Tags: stored-procedures, roles, stored-functions, sp-executesql, azure-managed-database

In our Azure Managed Instance DB, a new user has been created and given db_datareader, db_datawritter and db_ddladmin. As per [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15), db_ddladmin has CREATE PROCEDURE and ALTER ANY SCHEMA. But when logged in, I am unable to EXECUTE SPs and Functions. Then, separately gave EXECUTE permission.

Now the question is that under which fixed DB role EXECUTE comes? I am unable to find in MS document.

Answer (score 2):

`DB_Owner` has execute permission or create your own execute role like below against a database:

```
-- Create a db_executor role
CREATE ROLE db_executor

-- Grant execute rights to the new role
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
```